# Hydrolysis and Hydration

Tags: physical-chemistry

Does Ammonium Acetate, a salt of a weak base and weak acid, undergo both hydration and hydrolysis in aqeous solution? What is meant by the statement that " Some hydration reactions are hydrolysis"

Comment: Hydrolysis and hydration are quite totally unrelated.

Comment: :-) Quite or totally ? :-) Both involve water.

Answer (score 1):

- Hydrolysis is reaction with water, forming usually 2 different reaction products. It can be also named decomposition by water.
- Hydration is (usually) reversible chemical bonding of water. It can be also named water addition.
- One action of above can preceed or follow the other. If the hydration step preceeds hydrolysis in the reaction kinetics, the distinction may look vaque from some points of view.
- Ammonium acetate undergo hydrolysis.

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{CH3COONH4 &-> CH3COO- + NH4+} \\
\ce{CH3COO- + H3O+ &<=> CH3COOH + H2O } \\
\ce{CH3COO- + H2O &<=> CH3COOH + OH- } \\
\ce{NH4+ + H2O &<=> NH3 + H3O+} \\
\ce{NH4+ + OH- &<=> NH3 + H2O} \\
\ce{2 H2O &<=> H3O+ + OH-}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please note that $\ce{<->}$ arrow denotes resonance. For equilibrium or reversible reactions in general $\ce{<=>}$ is more suited (also it won't hurt to align a set of related reactions about the arrow marks:) ).

Comment: Yes, I know, I have forgotten to use =.
Also, it does not hurt if it is not aligned on the phone. :-) The markdown script is not available.

Comment: Well, you just confirmed the fact that phones are poorly suited for content creation:)

Comment: I have never needed that confirmation :-) But I am not going to publish my answer either. Additionally, the web editor alone is poorly suited either. :-)

Comment: I have never remembered until now, what is right, \align{begin}, or \begin{align}